# Debian - Switch back to the integrated wifi

Tags: debian, wifi, modprobe

I use Debian 8 and tonight I tried to switch between the integrated wifi and an wifi usb key using online tutorial. It worked. I did this just to see if wireless connection was better, but it isn't.

Now I would like to switch back to my integrated wifi... I'm using an Acer Aspire 7715. I used "modprobe mt7601Usta" as last command to install/use the wifi usb key, but how can I switch/reinstall (to) my integrated wifi now ? I tried to find the name of my wifi module, using "sudo lshw -C network". I got "AR928X" as wireless product.

Comment: Welcome to U&L . The `lspci` command will give you the required information about the wifi card e,g: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`  . You can edit your [question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/413333/edit)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/ath9k) the Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter use the `ath9k` driver. It is included in the linux kernel.

To unload the driver use:

```
sudo modprobe -rv ath9k
```

or

```
sudo rmmod ath9k
```

To load the driver use:

```
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

To unload the driver of your USB wifi adapter you can use  `modprobe -rv mt7601Usta` (the best command the `-v` = verbose) or the `rmmod mt7601Usta` command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I got :

insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath9k': Invalid argument

after using "sudo modprobe -v ath9k".

Comment: @Robg Disable the secure boot from your BIOS settings then try `sudo modprobe -rv ath9k` then `sudo modprobe -v ath9k`